# Somar letras e mostrar valor

Tags: c

Gente eu realmente não sei por onde começar,como posso resolver esse problema? Se alguém conseguir me dar dicas de como fazer,eu gradeceria.

FAZER um programa completo para tratar o problema descrito abaixo:

Três amigos resolveram comemorar o aniversário de um deles em um boteco.
Combinaram em "ratear" a conta dos tira-gostos consumidos entre todos,
pagar seu próprio consumo de bebidas e metade do que for consumido pelo aniversariante.
Se a conta for apresentada na forma abaixo (com possíveis repetições e fora de ordem):

```
                      0  tira gosto R$ww,ww
                      1 bebida      R$xx,xx // para o primeiro (aniversariante)
                      2 bebida     R$yy,yy //para o segundo
                      3 bebida      R$zz,zz //para o terceiro
```

Calcular e mostrar a parte que caberá a cada um pagar,para quitarem a conta.

```
int main()
{
    double tiragosto = "ww,ww";
    double bebida1   = "xx,xx";
    //double bebida2   = yy,yy;
    //double bebida3   = zz,zz;
    double calculo = 0.0;
    double amigo1A = 0.0;
    double amigo2 = 0.0;
    double amigo3 = 0.0;

    calculo = (tiragosto/bebida1);
    printf("resu: %lf",calculo);

    IO_pause   ( "Apertar ENTER para continuar." );
}
```

Nao da certo da maneira que faço..

Comment: Faltou você postar seu código e sua dúvida. Faça um tour (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e veja como perguntar. Aqui ninguém fará exercícios para você.

Comment: Se vc n leu direito,eu pedi dica de como somar as letras! Nao quero que façam o programa pra mim.

Comment: isso é um problema de matemática em primeiro lugar, só depois de resolvido o problema de matemática é que se torna um problema de programação

Comment: Acho entao que eu fiz confusao kkk, o certo seria o usuario digitar o valor da bebida consumida.... e eu resolver o calculo?

Comment: Se você declara uma variável com formato numérico (int, float, double, etc) você NÃO pode atribuir uma cadeia de caracteres a tal variável.

Comment: Posta a questão. Isso ajudaria muito.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde Bruna,

- **Quebrando o problema em pequenas partes:**

Primeiramente você pode fazer uma análise das regras que o seu problema pretende solucionar, segundo o enunciado temos:

1. O valor do tiragosto é dividido igualmente entre os três
2. O Aniversariante paga apenas metade do valor da bebida que ele consumiu
3. Os amigos vão pagar a sua bebida e mais metade da bebida do aniversariante

   **- Relacionando as regras com a solução:**

Podemos escrever as regras da seguinte forma:

1. rateioTiragosto = Tiragosto/3
2. rateioBebidaAniversariante = bebidaAniversariante/2
3. rateioBebidaAmigos = bebidaAmigo + bebidaAniversariante/2

Sabendo o que fazer é só dar asas à criatividade e escolher a forma de implementar.

**Dicas:**

Como mencionado por um dos usuários, variáveis do tipo numérico [`int`, `float`, `double` e etc] não podem ser inicializadas com caracteres, dessa forma já é visível o primeiro erro.

Para exibir apenas duas casas após a vírgula em C, você pode utilizar `%.Nlf`, onde **N** é a quantidade de números após a vírgula e **lf** se refere ao tipo de dado `double`.

Vou deixar o código final para caso a explicação não tenha ficado clara ou para o caso de você querer fazer consulta.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
double tiragosto = 0.0;
double bebidaAniversariante = 0.0;
double bebidaAmigo1 = 0.0;
double bebidaAmigo2 = 0.0;
double result  = 0.0;
double aniversariante = 0.0;
double amigo1  = 0.0;
double amigo2  = 0.0;


printf("Digite o valor do tiragosto, bebida aniversariante, bebida amigo 1 e bebida 
amigo 2 respectivamente!\n");
scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf",&tiragosto, &bebidaAniversariante, &bebidaAmigo1, 
&bebidaAmigo2);

result = tiragosto/3;
printf("0 tiragosto R$ %.2lf\n", result);
result = bebidaAniversariante/2;
printf("1 Bebida R$ %.2lf\n", result);
printf("2 Bebida R$ %.2lf\n", bebidaAmigo2+(result/2));
printf("3 Bebida R$ %.2lf\n", bebidaAmigo2+(result/2));

return 0;
}
```

Abraços e bons estudos!